# Conditional expectation (Poisson RV)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, solution-verification, expectation

The number of mistakes that are made by a writer on each page is a Poisson distributed random variable with parameter $\lambda$, independent for each page. A 3-page article is being rewritten by one of 4 writers, for who $\lambda$'s are equal respectively to $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$. Writer is chosen randomly with equal probability. What is the expected value of mistakes in whole article?

**My attempt**
$X$ - number of mistakes made on single page
$$\mathbb E(X)=1\cdot\frac{1}{4}+2\cdot\frac{1}{4}+3\cdot\frac{1}{4}+4\cdot\frac{1}{4}=2.5$$

$$3\cdot2.5=7.5$$

Anwser: $7.5$

Is that correct?

Comment: correct: another way of seeing it is to note that the parameter for each writer for the whole article would be $3,6,9,12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using the [conditional expectation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) over the writers $W_i$ to get 2.5,
$$E(X) = \sum E(X|W_i)P(W_i) $$

and then [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) to get $3\times2.5=7.5$
$$E(nX) = nE(X)$$